# SQL Server Reporting Service- datasets- grouping

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have table1 that is using dataset-A. I grouped this table by date. I have other dataset B which contains `total_qty` column.

I have to sum this column (`total_qty`) and show the result in table1 under  every group total.

Data set A columns:

```
Date
company_code
location_name
volumes
```

Data set B columns:

```
Date
Company_code
Total_Qty
```

How can I get `Sum(total_qty)` from dataset B into table1 under group total? Also, `total_Qty` should change as it is placed in group.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to **SUM** anything for DataSet B's **Company_code**, you can use a Lookup to get the value. You would need to match the **date and Company_code** from both tables.

```
=LookUp(CSTR(FIELDS!Company_code.VALUE) & "|" & CSTR(FIELDS!Date.VALUE),
        CSTR(FIELDS!Company_code.VALUE) & "|" & CSTR(FIELDS!Date.VALUE),
        ,FIELDS!Total_Qty.VALUE, "DataSetB")
```

This will combine your company code and date fields into one string and lookup the same combination in DataSet B.